# ThreeJS how to draw shape with curved edges

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to make a shape with threeJS that is made up of straight and curved edges. Currently I have the following:

[image]

I want the two top corners to be joined by a semi circle though so that it ends up being a square with a semi circle cut out of the top like so:

[image]

How would I do this? I've tried messing round with bezier curves and arcs but got nowhere. It needs to be a perfect circle though so that it lines up with the object below it.

My code at the moment is:

```
var Shape = new THREE.Shape();
Shape.lineTo(0, 4);
Shape.lineTo(2, 2);
Shape.lineTo(4, 4);
Shape.lineTo(4, 0);
Shape.lineTo(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
var Shape = new THREE.Shape();
Shape.absarc(2, 4, 2, Math.PI, Math.PI * 2);
Shape.lineTo(4, 0);
Shape.lineTo(0, 0);
```

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(3, 5, 8);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));

var Shape = new THREE.Shape();
Shape.absarc(2, 4, 2, Math.PI, Math.PI * 2);
Shape.lineTo(4, 0);
Shape.lineTo(0, 0);

var shapeGeom = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry(Shape);
var shapeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x00ff00,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
var shapeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(shapeGeom, shapeMaterial);
scene.add(shapeMesh);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're my hero!

Answer (score 0):

You can create the shape you want by modifying one of the shapes in http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html:

```
var trackShape = new THREE.Shape();

trackShape.moveTo( 40, 40 );
trackShape.lineTo( 40, 160 );
trackShape.absarc( 60, 160, 20, Math.PI, 0, false );
trackShape.lineTo( 80, 40 );
//trackShape.moveTo( 40, 40 ); // optional. shape will auto-close
```

three.js r.96